# How to extract height and width from dimensions string in R using stringr?

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I have a column with dimensions strings in the following format:

> 41 1/4 x 29 3/8" (104.8 x 74.6 cm)
>   7' 1" x 31" (216 x 78.8 cm)
>   6' 6 3/4" x 6' 6 3/4" (200 x 200 cm)

How do I extract the height and width in cm to a separate column each?
I want to use `stringr` and `dplyr`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can try

```
library(stringr)
do.call(rbind, 
    lapply(str_extract_all(df1$Col1, 
       "(?<=\\()[0-9.]+|[0-9.]+(?=\\scm)"), as.numeric))
#      [,1]  [,2]
#[1,] 104.8  74.6
#[2,] 216.0  78.8
#[3,] 200.0 200.0
```

---

If we need to use `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(purrr)
 str_extract_all(df1$Col1, "(?<=\\()[0-9.]+|[0-9.]+(?=\\scm)") %>% 
       map(~as.numeric(.)) %>% 
       do.call(rbind,.)
#  [,1]  [,2]
#[1,] 104.8  74.6
#[2,] 216.0  78.8
#[3,] 200.0 200.0
```

---

Or with `extract` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
extract(df1, Col1, into=c("Col1", "Col2"), 
          "^[^(]+\\(([0-9.]+)\\D+([0-9.]+).*")
#   Col1 Col2
#1 104.8 74.6
#2   216 78.8
#3   200  200
```

Comment: Thank you for showing different ways. That was very helpful.